# Sample 70% of Data into a new dataframe

Tags: r

I must be doing something wrong. I am trying to create a new dataframe with a random sampling of 70% of my primary dataframe - carsdata.

```
set.seed(80915974)
my.sample.70=carsdata[sample(carsdata)*.7, replace = TRUE]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `slice_sample`

```
library(dplyr)
my.sample.70 <- carsdata %>%
    slice_sample(prop = 0.7)
```

---

Or if we use the `base R`

```
my.sample.70 <- carsdata[sample(nrow(carsdata), nrow(carsdata) * 0.7), replace = TRUE),]
```

---

Using a reproducible example

```
mtcars %>%  
    slice_sample(prop = 0.7)
#                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#Volvo 142E          21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
#Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
#Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
#Honda Civic         30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
#Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
#Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
#Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
#Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
#Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Merc 280C           17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
#Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
#Lotus Europa        30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
#Toyota Corona       21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
#Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
#Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#Fiat X1-9           27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
#Ferrari Dino        19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
#Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
#AMC Javelin         15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
#Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
```

Comment: yes, I see. Thank you. I used the base R and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @akrun. Simple & efficient method with base R! Worth noting though, this method may not create a randomized sample, as the choice is limited to first 70% of rows - may introduce sample bias.

Comment: @Pittoro is right, it should have been `sample(nrow(carsdata), nrow(carsdata) * 0.7)` to sample 70% of the whole dataframe with no repeats.

Answer (score 2):

Another base R option using `subset` + `sample`

```
subset(carsdata,sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), nrow(carsdata), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.7, 0.3)))
```